# how to get the date from datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I have a datetime object and I'm trying to individually get a string with the date, and one with the time.  I'd like the values for theDate and theTime to be strings.

```
theDate = myDatetime.date()
theTime = myDatetime.time()
```

Something along those lines.  I tried str(datetime.date) but it gave me a reference in memory, any other ideas?  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Checking the official documentation is always a good first step. It looks like method you are looking for is findable there by searching for "string" in the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`datetime.strftime()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) on the datetime object:

```
theDate = myDatetime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
theTime = myDatetime.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

Alternatively, turn your `date` and `time` objects into strings for their default string representations:

```
theDate = str(myDatetime.date())
theTime = str(myDatetime.time())
```

Demo:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> myDatetime = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> myDatetime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
'2013-06-19'
>>> myDatetime.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
'16:49:44'
>>> str(myDatetime.date())
'2013-06-19'
>>> str(myDatetime.time())
'16:49:44.447010'
```

The default string format for `datetime.time` objects includes the microsecond component.