# Dealing with timestamp attribute in python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe 'df' in which one of the attribute is date time. Values in this attributes are shown below:

```
>>df['TR_DATE']
0         2015-03-18 19:59:58 
1         2015-03-19 13:23:37
2         2015-03-19 13:27:04
3         2015-03-19 14:23:53
4         2015-03-19 15:01:50
5         2015-03-19 17:45:42
6         2015-03-19 17:49:58
```

I want to split the values in this attribute as date and time separately. so that I will have two new columns df['DATE'] and df['TIME'] which contain the values:

```
>>df['DATE']
         2015-03-18  
         2015-03-19 
         2015-03-19 
         2015-03-19
         2015-03-19 
         2015-03-19 
         2015-03-19 
>>df['Time']
         19:59:58 
         13:23:37
         13:27:04
         14:23:53
         15:01:50
         17:45:42
         17:49:58
```

How I can do this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22625698/python-split-timestamp-by-date-and-hour

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17194657/1278112

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get the date from datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17194657/how-to-get-the-date-from-datetime)

Comment: @ShiheZhang those questions are for python datetime objects and not specific to `pandas`

Answer (score 6):

The following should work:

```
In[229]:
df['DATE'] = df['TR_DATE'].dt.date
df['TIME'] = df['TR_DATE'].dt.time
df

Out[229]: 
              TR_DATE        DATE      TIME
0 2015-03-18 19:59:58  2015-03-18  19:59:58
1 2015-03-19 13:23:37  2015-03-19  13:23:37
2 2015-03-19 13:27:04  2015-03-19  13:27:04
3 2015-03-19 14:23:53  2015-03-19  14:23:53
4 2015-03-19 15:01:50  2015-03-19  15:01:50
5 2015-03-19 17:45:42  2015-03-19  17:45:42
6 2015-03-19 17:49:58  2015-03-19  17:49:58
```

datetime columns have the `.dt` accessor to return [`dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html#pandas.Series.dt.date) and [`dt.time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html#pandas.Series.dt.time) components.

Note this returns `datetime.date` and `datetime.time` objects which don't support vectorised operations.

This assumes that the dtype is already datetime, if not then you need to convert using [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df['TR_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TR_DATE']
```

prior to the above calls

If you just want `str` representations, you can call [`dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html#pandas.Series.dt.strftime):

```
In[231]:
df['DATE'] = df['TR_DATE'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
df['TIME'] = df['TR_DATE'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
df

Out[231]: 
              TR_DATE        DATE      TIME
0 2015-03-18 19:59:58  2015-03-18  19:59:58
1 2015-03-19 13:23:37  2015-03-19  13:23:37
2 2015-03-19 13:27:04  2015-03-19  13:27:04
3 2015-03-19 14:23:53  2015-03-19  14:23:53
4 2015-03-19 15:01:50  2015-03-19  15:01:50
5 2015-03-19 17:45:42  2015-03-19  17:45:42
6 2015-03-19 17:49:58  2015-03-19  17:49:58
```

Again as these are strings you can't perform arithmetical operations